# Transferring information between sheets based on column headings

Tags: vba, excel

This function conditionally copies and pastes information from one sheet to another based on the column headings to standardize data before exported to SQL database.

I am not an expert in VBA and started learning but when I run this code, it takes way too long to process huge data (ex: Excel sheet with 70k rows would take like 2 minutes to 5 minutes). Can anyone make a suggestion to make it time-efficient?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub projectionTemplateFormat()

    Dim t1 As Double, t2 As Double

    xlSpeed True

        t1 = Timer
        'On Error Resume Next
        mainProcess
        'On Error GoTo 0
        t2 = Timer

    xlSpeed False

    MsgBox "Duration: " & t2 - t1 & " seconds"

End Sub

Private Sub mainProcess()

    Const SPACE_DELIM   As String = " "

    Dim wsIndex             As Worksheet
    Dim wsImport            As Worksheet    'Raw
    Dim wsFinal             As Worksheet

    Dim indexHeaderCol      As Range
    Dim msg                 As String

    Dim importHeaderRng     As Range
    Dim importColRng        As Range
    Dim importHeaderFound   As Variant
    Dim importLastRow       As Long

    Dim finalHeaderRng      As Range
    Dim finalColRng         As Range
    Dim finalHeaderRow      As Variant
    Dim finalHeaderFound    As Variant
    Dim header              As Variant      'Each item in the FOR loop
    Dim lastRow As Long  'Manual Headers based on the number of rows in the raw data
    Dim rngs As Range


    Set wsIndex = aIndex    'This is the Code Name; top-left pane: aIndex (Index)
    Set wsImport = bImport  'Direct reference to Code Name: bImport.Range("A1")
    Set wsFinal = cFinal    'Reference using Sheets collection: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")
    Set rngs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Cells


    lastRow = rngs.Find(What:="*", After:=rngs.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
    '+ 1 is added for dummy row in the final sheet; otherwise it won't copy the last row in the import sheet

    'Static Data(Account Level information)
    wsFinal.Range("D3:D" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H2").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AD3:AD" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H3").Value
    wsFinal.Range("X3:X" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H4").Value
    wsFinal.Range("Y3:Y" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H5").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AF3:AF" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H6").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AG3:AG" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H7").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AE3:AE" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H8").Value
    wsFinal.Range("F3:F" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H9").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AC3:AC" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("INDEX").Range("H10").Value

    'Claim Type
    wsFinal.Range("E3:E" & lastRow).Value = "AB"





    With wsImport.UsedRange
        Set importHeaderRng = .Rows(1)      'Import - Headers
        importLastRow = .Rows.Count + 1         'Import - Total Rows; + 1 is for taking into consideration of the dummy row in the final sheet
    End With

    With wsFinal.UsedRange
        finalHeaderRow = .Rows(1)           'Final - Headers (as Array)
        Set finalHeaderRng = .Rows(1)       'Final - Headers (as Range)
    End With


    With wsIndex.UsedRange  'Transpose col 3 from Index (without the header), as column names in Import
        Set indexHeaderCol = .Columns(3).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
        wsImport.Range(wsImport.Cells(1, 1), wsImport.Cells(1, .Rows.Count - 1)).Value2 = Application.Transpose(indexHeaderCol)
    End With


    If Len(aIndex.Cells(1, 1).Value2) > 0 Then 'if index cell (1,1) is not empty

        With Application

            For Each header In finalHeaderRow   'Loop through all headers in Final

                If Len(Trim(header)) > 0 Then   'If the Final heade is not empty

                    importHeaderFound = .Match(header, importHeaderRng, 0)          'Find header in Import sheet

                    If IsError(importHeaderFound) Then
                        msg = msg & vbLf & header & SPACE_DELIM & wsImport.Name     'Import doesn't have current header
                    Else

                        finalHeaderFound = .Match(header, finalHeaderRng, 0)        'Find header in Final sheet

                        If IsError(finalHeaderFound) Then
                            msg = msg & vbLf & header & SPACE_DELIM & wsFinal.Name  'Import doesn't have current header
                        Else

                            With wsImport
                                Set importColRng = .UsedRange.Columns(importHeaderFound).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                            End With

                            With wsFinal
                                Set finalColRng = .Range(.Cells(3, finalHeaderFound), .Cells(importLastRow, finalHeaderFound)) 'Change 3 to 2 if the dummy row is not included
                                finalColRng.Value2 = vbNullString                   'Delete previous values (entire column)
                            End With


                            finalColRng.Value2 = importColRng.Value2             'Copy Import data in Final columns

                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next header
        End With

        ConvertToUppercase
        extractYears
Dim i As Long
       For i = 3 To lastRow

          If Not (wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value <= 2015 And wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value >= 1910) Then
            With wsFinal
                .Cells(i, "Q").ClearContents
            End With

          End If
       Next i

       Dim j As Long
          For j = 3 To lastRow

          If Not (wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value <= 2015 And wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value >= 1910) Then
            With wsFinal
                .Cells(j, "R").ClearContents
            End With

          End If

       Next j




          wsFinal.Columns("G").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("I").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("K").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("B").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "@"
          'wsFinal.Columns("R").NumberFormat = "@"
          'wsFinal.Columns("Q").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("J").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("L").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("T").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("W").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("V").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("AD").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("N").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
          wsFinal.Columns("AN").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
          wsFinal.Columns("AO").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
          wsFinal.Columns("AP").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
          'wsFinal.Columns("AQ").NumberFormat = "General"

 applyFormat wsFinal.Range(wsFinal.Cells(2, 1), wsFinal.Cells(importLastRow, wsFinal.UsedRange.Columns.Count))




    Dim ws As Worksheet
       For Each ws In Worksheets
       ws.Select
       ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
    Next ws

    Else
        MsgBox "Missing raw data (Sheet 2 - 'Import')", vbInformation, "   Missing Raw Data"
    End If

End Sub
```

**Function 2**

```
 Private Sub extractYears()

        Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, ur As Range, colW As Long, colV As Long

        Set ur = cFinal.UsedRange                   '3rd sheet

        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ur) > 0 Then

            colW = colNum("Q")
            colV = colNum("R")

            arr = ur                                'transfer sheet data to memory

            For i = 3 To getMaxCell(ur).Row         'each "row"

                If Len(arr(i, colW)) > 0 Then       'if not empty
                    If Len(arr(i, colW)) > 4 Then   'if it's full date (longer than 4 digits)
                        arr(i, colW) = Format(arr(i, colW), "yyyy") 'extract the year part
                    End If
                End If                              'if it contains 4 digit year leave it as is

                If Len(arr(i, colV)) > 0 Then       'the same logic applied for colV
                    If Len(arr(i, colV)) > 4 Then
                        arr(i, colV) = Format(arr(i, colV), "yyyy")
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            ur = arr                                'transfer memory data back to sheet

        End If
    End Sub
```

**Function 2**

```
Private Sub applyFormat(ByRef rng As Range)
    With rng
        '.ClearFormats

        With .Font
            .Name = "Georgia"
            .Color = RGB(0, 0, 225)
        End With
        .Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
        With .Rows(1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders
            .LineStyle = xlDot  'xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With


    End With



    refit rng
End Sub

Sub ConvertToUppercase()

   Dim ws As Object
   Dim LCell As Range

   'Move through each sheet in your spreadsheet

      On Error Resume Next
      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FINAL").Activate

      'Convert all constants and text values to proper case
      For Each LCell In Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues)
         LCell.Formula = UCase(LCell.Formula)
      Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Its also good to provide us some context about what the code *does*. I'm much more likely to answer a question if I don't have to waste time figuring that out myself.

Comment: Okay I might edit the original post

Comment: I could probably try **if** I could compile your project! What is `xlSpeed`? Could you also show the code where the, presumably, `Public Variables` aIndex, bImport and cFinal are declared and populated? A redacted copy of your sheets would be helpful too.

Comment: Your first step should be to use the `Timer` function inside your `mainProcess` to work out which part of the code takes the most time - is it the main loop or the call to `ConvertToUppercase` or `extractYears` or the final loop.

Comment: I agree here with @MarkFitzgerald - what is `xlspeed` and are aIndex, bImport and cFinal placeholders for actual sheets? Some test data would also be useful.

Comment: Does this code actually compile  for you in a clean workbook? There are so many Debug...Compile errors which, after commented out, leave you with, fairly much, nothing!  Post **all of your code** or delete the question because there is no possibility of an answer as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned in the Comments, it is difficult/impossible to offer specific suggestions without a more complete overview of the code/project/data.

However, I can offer a general piece of advice:

**Put all your data in an array before you do anything to/with it.**

Interacting directly with workbooks/sheets takes an order of magnitude (at least) more time than interacting with an array.

If you only have one point at the start when you put all the data into an array, and one point at the end where you paste the data from an array into the second worksheet, everything that happens in between should run an order of magnitude faster